# Amazon CloudWatchLogs putLogEvents in PHP gives error tooOldLogEventEndIndex

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, zend-framework2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to put Log on amazon CloudWatchLogs like this:

```
$response2 = $amzonLoger->putLogEvents([

            'logGroupName' => 'myGroup',
            'logStreamName' => 'myStream',
            'logEvents' => [
                [
                    'timestamp' => time(),
                    'message' => 'message'
                ],
            ],
            'sequenceToken' => lastToken,
        ]);
        var_dump($response2);
```

but always i've this response :

```
bject(Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model)#289 (2) { ["structure":protected]=> NULL ["data":protected]=> array(2) { ["nextSequenceToken"]=> string(56) "495401145812734324234234236420825819917076850" ["rejectedLogEventsInfo"]=> array(1) { ["tooOldLogEventEndIndex"]=> int(1) } } }
```

Can you help me understanding what does mean `["rejectedLogEventsInfo"]=> array(1) { ["tooOldLogEventEndIndex"]=> int(1)`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the solution adding this line instead of `time()` function of php . following this [example cloudWatchLogs](https://www.mind-it.info/2015/08/12/aws-cloudwatch-logs-php-example/).

```
'timestamp' =>  round(microtime(true) * 1000),
```

I hope that this can help someone on the future.

Comment: 2024! its work for me.

Answer (score 7):

Cloudwatch API expects timestamp in epoch **milliseconds**, not seconds. Took me a while to figure that out. Thanks to the PHP snippet above.

Comment: Actually, milliseconds -- but this comment is what worked it out for me.

Comment: I corrected the answer to milliseconds in case anyone's confused about the above comment. For anyone interested, it's documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-log-events.html) that it's milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

Your error is telling you that the timestamp you are using is not good.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html

From doc:

> None of the log events in the batch can be more than 2 hours in the
>   future.
>   None of the log events in the batch can be older than 14 days
>   or the retention period of the log group.

If using current time and current time is correct you may be in a different time zone (that is more than 2 hours ahead of UTC). Use UTC time for events timestamp.